# SWIG C++ to Python: terminate called after throwing an instance of ... Aborted

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to write a SWIG module, and I can't seem to figure out how to catch exceptions from C++ and propagate them up to Python. Here's a simplified version of my code:

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"

Looper::Looper() {

    nframes = 0;

}

void Looper::set_nframes(int nf) {

   if (nf < 0) {
        throw LooperValueError();
   }   

   nframes = nf; 

}

int Looper::get_nframes(void) {

   return nframes;

}
```

example.h:

```
class LooperValueError {}; 

class Looper {

    private:
        int nframes;

    public:
        Looper();
        void set_nframes(int);
        int get_nframes(void);

};
```

example.i:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"

%exception {
    try {
        $function
    } catch (LooperValueError) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Looper value out of range");
        return NULL;
    }   
}
```

This builds fine. But then in Python, when I call Looper.set_nframes(-2), I don't get a ValueError like I'd expect; instead the code interpreter crashes with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'LooperValueError'
Aborted
```

It seems the exception is not being caught by the wrapper. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of `%exception` is local only to the declarations that follow it. You wrote `%exception` after `%include`, so it doesn't actually get applied to anything. (Have a look in the generated code to validate this - your try/catch block won't actually have made it through to the output yet).

So your interface should look like this instead:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%exception {
    try {
        $function
    } catch (const LooperValueError&) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Looper value out of range");
        return NULL;
    }   
}

%include "example.h"
```

One more minor point I tweaked: normally you should prefer to [catch exceptions by const reference](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=373339) instead of by value.